# Assert element color in Selenium IDE

Tags: html, css, selenium, automation, assert

I'm trying to setup a test automation that will assert an element color when clicked. However, I couldn't find the right way to do it. I'm a selenium newbie, I have tried every possible way to do it but failed.

HTML:

```
<a class="mg-friend-12345 friend selected" title="test" data-cid="12345" style="">
```

CSS:

```
.imweb #mgifting-dialog .mg-friends .friend.selected, .imweb #mgifting-dialog .mg-friends .non-friend.selected {
  background-color: #9DD4FD;
}
```

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the idea be the following:
we simply need to get css property(color, in particulat) of element  before click. and get css property(color ) of the element after click on it.

so it be like (I work on java and we will execute a piece of javascript using jsExecutor to implement getColor function. It will take css selector of the element. And get return its color):

```
public String jsGetColor(String css){
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x=$(\'"+css+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("return x.css('color')");
        //stringBuilder.append("return x.css('background-color')");
        String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
        return res;
    }

String cssSelectorLink="a[class='mg-friend-12345 friend selected']";
WebElement linkToClick = driver.findElemebt(By.cssSelector(cssSelectorLink));
String colorBeforeClick = jsGetColor(cssSelectorLink);
linkToClick.click();
String colorAfterClick = jsGetColor(cssSelectorLink);
Assert.assertFalse(colorBeforeClick.equals(colorAfterClick));
```

Hope it be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I'm a bit confused on how to use these codes since I'm a noob lol. Can you please tell me how to simply use these codes and how to just use the command, target, and value boxes?

Comment: ohhh.. sorry. I got misconfused. You question is related to selnium IDE. And I work with selenium webdriver +java. I'm noob in selenium IDE :) I can explain you how you can set up IDE and write your tests e.g. in java

Comment: It's alright! I appreciate your help! Please teach me how I can set up IDE and write my tests e.g. in java. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

well I work in intelij IDEA. So setUp to write selenium tests e.g. be the following:

1) install maven

- Unzip the distribution archive, i.e. apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.zip to
  the directory you wish to install Maven 3.0.4. These instructions
  assume you chose C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation. The
  subdirectory apache-maven-3.0.4 will be created from the archive.
- Add    the M2_HOME environment variable by opening up the system
  properties    (WinKey + Pause), selecting the "Advanced" tab, and the
  "Environment    Variables" button, then adding the M2_HOME variable
  in the user    variables with the value C:\Program Files\Apache
  Software    Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.4. Be sure to omit any
  quotation marks    around the path even if it contains spaces.
- In    the same dialog, add    the M2 environment variable in the user
  variables with the    value %M2_HOME%\bin.

2) install jdk
3) [image]

4) verify that all environment variables you've set properly
[image]
5) run intelij IDEA
select Project structure to set up installed  JDK
[image]
6)
press New.select jsdk. write path where we installed  java,  e.g C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29
[image]
7)create new project from scratch
[image]
8) maven module
[image]
9) [image]
10) [image]
11) add to POM appropriate dependencies:
[image]

```
   <dependency>
 <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> 
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId> 
<version>2.24.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

12) if still someting underline with red line , press alt+enter on it >> idea should automatically suggest autoimport.

13)test structure in the project
[image]

14)common structure  of selenium test

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class HomePageTest extends SeleneseTestBase{

    static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void openFirefox(){

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @Test
    public void testHomePage(){
        driver.get("https://www.google.by/");
        WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gbqfq\"]"));
        search.sendKeys("laptop");
        search.submit();

    }

    @After
    public void closeFirefox(){
        // driver.quit();
    }
}
```

15) also don't forget that you can export your created test in selenium IDE as JUNIT4- selenium and open them in IDEA
[image]

Regards